# How to install package without install dependencies through "package"?

Tags: package, use-package

I am using `:ensure t` of `use-package` to install "go-prjectile" package which depends on "go-rename". But I would like to use a local version of "go-rename" and its path is already added to `load-path`.

My configuration:

```
(use-package go-rename
   :load-path "lisp/go-rename")

(use-package go-projectile
   :ensure t)
```

But every time when "go-projectile" is installed, the "go-rename" is also installed from melpa too.

Is there any way to only install "go-projectile" without install its dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thanks for the answer from @chenbin. All the following ideas from his answer and blog post.

Maybe I have some mis-understand on the 4 step way to create local elpa. For me to manually maintain it is painful (For example, package from git repo, keep updating).

After some googling about "local elpa" I steal code (Makefile, package-build.el) from "melpa" which would build local elpa `packages` and `archive-contents` from `recipes`.

Then I only need to maintain recipes something like below (use `ob-go` as example)

```
(ob-go
 :fetcher github
 :repo "pope/ob-go")
```

The make file would cache the package from Github and create `archive-contents` to `packages` directory.

Then I just need to add `("local-elpa" . "~/.emacs.d/packages")` to `package-archives` and pin it to `local-elpa`.

If local elpa packages has updates, just make the packages and archive-contents, then update packages as usual.

Comment: You might be reinventing [quelpa](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa)

Comment: @npostavs, that looks great, but does it support `pin` package to avoid to the package is installed on `melpa` if it is a dependency package whose version on `melpa` is higher than my forked repo's one?

Comment: AFAIK, it creates a normal package archive, so pinning works as usual (I'm not a user, so I can't say for sure though).

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest solution is to tell `package.el` that you have already `lsp-mode` mode.  You can do it in two different ways:

1. If you have installed `lsp-mode` in a format/layout that `package.el` can understand (most importantly it contains both `<pkg>-autoloads.els` and `<pkg>-pkg.el`), then just make sure that it is in one of the directories mentioned in `package-directory-list`).
2. If you installed it using a different format/layout, then use something like:

   ```
   (add-to-list 'package--builtin-versions `(go-rename 1 2 1))
   ```

   It is important to do this early, i.e. before `package-activate-all` or `package-initialize` is called, so in Emacs≥27, you will want to put it into your `early-init.el`.

Answer (score 1):

See http://blog.binchen.org/posts/how-to-manage-emacs-packages-effectively.html which provides complete solution for Emacs 23.4, 24.3, 24.4, 25.

In your case, the easiest way is to setup your own package repository `localelpa`:

Step 1, create directory `~/.emacs.d/localelpa`

Step 2,  create file `~/.emacs.d/localelpa/archive-contents` with below content

```
(1
 (go-rename . [(1 2 1) nil "This is go-rename, blah blah" single])
)
```

Step 3, place go-rename-1.2.1.el at `~/.emacs.d/localelpa`

Step 4, insert below code into `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and restart Emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("localelpa" . "~/.emacs.d/localelpa"))
```

Now you will see package goname-1.2.1 after `M-x list-packages`, in Emacs 24.4 you can tweak `package-pinned-packages` to pin that package (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html)

What about Emacs 24.3, 23.4? Well, why not change version from 1.2.1 to 99.9.9? ;)

Comment: the 4 steps solution seems a lot of work. I have read your blog posts. The whitelist one sounds great. Is it possible to have a blacklist version? Will that work depended packages?

Comment: This is the minimum setup. Once you setup localelpa, you can use it for other packages. Surely you can use blacklist strategy. It's just boolean expression in package-filter-function.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem. I was trying to use a local version of `lsp-mode` but packages which depended on it were installing `lsp-mode` from melpa. @chenbin's solution would successfully filter out `lsp-mode` from the package list (i.e. when you `M-x list-packages`) but it would still be installed when installing any packages for which it was a dependency.

I'm using `(use-package)` to specify the load path of my manually installed packages. Adding this code **before** `(package-initialize)` is called works for me:

```
(defvar local-only-packages
  '(lsp-mode)
  "Don't install these packages as dependencies, I will install them manually.")

;; When determining dependencies to install, filter out any packages you will
;; handle manually.
(advice-add
 'package-compute-transaction
 :filter-return
 (lambda (packages)
   (seq-filter (lambda (it)
         (not (memq (package-desc-name it) local-only-packages)))
           packages)))


;; When creating package-descriptions that will be initialized by
;; package.el, filter out the dependncies that are handled manually. 
(advice-add
 'package-desc-from-define
 :filter-return
 (lambda (pkg-desc)
   (setf (package-desc-reqs pkg-desc)
     (seq-filter (lambda (it)
               (not (memq (car it) local-only-packages)))
             (package-desc-reqs pkg-desc)))
   pkg-desc))
```